# Angular Unknown provider. Netsted controllers

Tags: angularjs

I cannot work out how to call a method in another angular controller.
On the webpage there is another angular app. I want to use some of the functionality from the other app. As soon as i add the other controller to my html I get this error when the page loads:

```
Unknown provider: documentsServiceProvider <- documentsService <- documentActionsController
```

My code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("documentActionsController", SomeNameSpace.DocumentActionsController)
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
```

Markup

```
<div id="qms-part-docApp" ng-controller="myController" >
        <tr ng-repeat="fileInfo in documentList track by $index">
            <a ng-controller="documentActionsController"  ng-click="addToFavorites()"></a></td>
```

I want to call a method on this documentActionsController (TypeScript compiled)

```
var Controllers;
        (function (Controllers) {
            var DocumentActionsController = (function (_super) {
                __extends(DocumentActionsController, _super);
                function DocumentActionsController($scope, documentsService, basketService, favoritesService) {
                    var _this = this;
                    _super.call(this, $scope);
                    this.$scope = $scope;
                    this.documentsService = documentsService;
                    this.basketService = basketService;
                    this.favoritesService = favoritesService;
                    this.init = function () {
                        _this.$scope.addToFavorites = _this.addToFavorites;
                        _this.$scope.removeFromFavorites = _this.removeFromFavorites;
                        _this.$scope.addToBasket = _this.addToBasket;
                        _this.$scope.removeFromBasket = _this.removeFromBasket;
                        _this.$scope.markAsRead = _this.markAsRead;
                        _this.$scope.isItInFavorites = _this.isItInFavorites;
                        _this.$scope.isItInBasket = _this.isItInBasket;
                        _this.$scope.isItRead = _this.isItRead;
                    };
                    this.addToFavorites = function (id, title, owner, url, icon, path) {
                        SomeNamespace.addToFavorites(id, title, owner, url, icon, path);
                    };
                    this.removeFromFavorites = function (id, path) {
                        SomeNamespace.removeFromFavorites(id, path);
                    };
                    this.addToBasket = function (id, title, owner, url, icon, filename) {
                        SomeNamespace.addToBasket(id, title, owner, url, icon, filename);
                    };
                    this.removeFromBasket = function (id) {
                        SomeNamespace.removeFromBasket(id);
                    };
                    this.markAsRead = function (id, version) {
                        SomeNamespace.markAsRead(id, version);
                    };
                    this.isItInFavorites = function (id) {
                        SomeNamespace.isItInFavorites(id);
                    };
                    this.isItInBasket = function (id) {
                        SomeNamespace.isItInBasket(id);
                    };
                    this.isItRead = function (id, version) {
                        SomeNamespace.isItRead(id, version);
                    };
                    this.init();
                }
                DocumentActionsController.$inject = [
                    "$scope",
                    "documentsService",
                    "basketService",
                    "favoritesService"
                ];
                return DocumentActionsController;
```

Comment: Register all services(`"documentsService", "basketService", favoritesService"`) with the module.

Comment: Like this: ?

angular.module('myApp', ['documentsService', 'basketService', 'favoritesService'])
.controller("documentActionsController", SomeNameSpace.DocumentActionsController)
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) like this,

```
      angular.module('myApp', [])
        .service("documentsService", function(){
          // write code
    })
        .service("basketService", function(){
         //  write your code
    })
        .service("favoritesService", function(){
            //  write your code
    })
        .controller("documentActionsController", SomeNameSpace.DocumentActionsController)
        .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
```